# How does certificate revocation work with intermediate CA's?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, certificate-revocation

Suppose a PKI hierarchy like below.

```
root CA ==> inter-1 CA ==> user-1
  \
   \======> inter-2 CA ==> user-2
```

My question is: does root CA also need to periodically download CRL from its children: inter-1 and inter-2?

Since user-1 and user-2 can authenticate each other, if user-2's certificate is revoked by inter-2, inter-2 should let root know and then propagate to inter-1 and user-1, right?

If so, it seems quite complicated. Is there any tool to use for managing the revocation logic? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, revocation of certificate is not propagated across the CA tree. Each CA (root and intermediate in your case) is responsible of the publication of the CRL containing the list of **only the revoked certificates that were issued by this CA**.

An example:

Root CA publishes a CRL for the certificates issued by Root CA: inter-1 CA and inter-2 CA. Root CA is not aware of the user-1 and user-2 certificates or their revocation status.

inter-1 CA (resp inter-2 CA) publishes a CRL containing the list of revoked certificates issued by inter-1 CA (resp inter-2 CA) and only these certificates.

```
CRL Root CA   CRL inter-1 CA 
  ^             ^
  |             |
root CA ==> inter-1 CA ==> user-1
  |
  |           CRL inter-2 CA 
  |             ^
  \             |
   \======> inter-2 CA ==> user-2
```

if user-1 certificate is revoked, this certificate (actually its serial number) will only appear in the CRL published by inter-1 CA.

When someone wants to check the validity the user-1 certificate the process is as follows:

1. build the certificate chain between the certificate and a trusted CA: user-1 / inter-1 CA / root CA
2. fetch the CRL for the first certificate in the list
3. verify the signature of the CRL
4. check the status of the first certificate in the list against this CRL
5. if the status is not revoked, remove the certificate from the list and go to 2. otherwise fail
6. if the list contains only the trusted CA, check the chain of signature of the certificates (a certificate must be signed by the following certificate in the list)
7. if all signature have been checked and are valid, the user-1 certificate is valid.

Note that validating the CRL signature can trigger a validation of another certificate chain : i.e. this algorithm can be recursive. Actually the X.509 certificate validation algorithm is (very) complex and I just summarize the principles here.

Comment: JCS, could you give me a precise reference (RFC/chapter) where you found this algorithm for the validation of the trust chain? i couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Gab Look at RFC 5280, section #6 "Certification Path Validation"  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#page-71

Comment: @JCS yes it is the same rfc I know. That section describes how to build a certification path. Still i can't find anywhere that each certificate in the chain must be validated against its crl. Your algorithm is reasonable but I really would like to find it. Plus one of the possible reason for the revocation of a certificate in a crl is "caCompromise". This really confuses me.

Comment: @Gab Maybe I did not fully understand your question but that section is more than path building in the sense that validation is part of path building since the outcome of the algo is supposed to be a "valid" path.
For instance the section 6.1.3 describes the certificate validation process and more specifically it is said: "[Verify that] at the current time, the certificate is not revoked. This may be determined by obtaining the appropriate CRL (Section 6.3), by status information, or by out-of-band mechanisms." Moreover the section 6.3 describes the CRL validation

Comment: @JCS After a lot of thinking i decided your answer is right. There is no reference to the algorithm you explained in the RFC5280 but the rule we can infer from the spec is: if a certificate has a CDP that must be verified against a CRL. And your algorithm does so. Also you can't just verify the CRL of the user certificate (if the CA private key is compromised the user certificate may have been forged). +1 to your answer.

Comment: Nice answer. Seems that the order of checking the chain should be reversed though. The RFC appears to start from the trust anchor (Root CA in this case), and eventually ending up at the target (user-1).
`for all x in {1, ..., n-1}, the subject of certificate x is the issuer of certificate x+1` on https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#page-72